# how to use update in detail view

Tags: c#, asp.net

There is button Update in detail veiw which automatically transform the column to textbox can any body tell me where to code the update code;in .aspx or in .aspxcs

Comment: Could you clarify what you are looking help with?

Answer (score 0):

Edit -> will switch the detailsview mode to editing

Update -> will save changes by calling the DetailsView OnUpdating event, depending on your datasource this can call an update method on your back end.